# If Eric Koenig was an LMD, why was it not discovered during his post-mortem?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of SHIELD* first season, Grant Ward kills Agent Eric Koenig. Later in the 7th season, we are revealed that all the Koenig's were LMDs. If that was the case, then why didn't Jemma Simmons discover that fact when she performs Autopsy on Eric Koenig?

Comment: Oh! I don't remember which episode exactly. It was said sometime in season 7, when they go back in time to save Wilfred Mallick. A Koenig is the owner of a bar there. I think it comes up when discussing with him. Lemme see if I can find that episode.

Comment: May be. Now that you say it, it seems so. May be they just mentioned something around that lines and I took it as them explicitly saying it. Thanks!

Comment: You are mistaken. That's not revealed at all, and isn't true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Later in the 7th season, we are revealed that all the Koenig's were LMDs.

### Actually, no, they weren't.

There is a lot of speculation that somehow the conversation between Enoch and Ernest Koenig somehow confirmed that the SHIELD Koenigs were LMDs but this is not borne out by the transcripts.

All Ernest said was that he wanted to know more about robots. Enoch says that Ernest's grandchildren (the SHIELD Koenigs) will also find it fascinating.

> EK: You're hired. But I have a couple of conditions. First, I want to know more about this S.H.I.E.L.D. outfit. I feel like I could be a help there.
>
> Enoch: Indeed, you will. As will this fine establishment. What is the second condition?
>
> EK: I want to know all there is to know about robots.
>
> Enoch: Chronicoms.
>
> EK: Whatever you call yourselves. I-I find it fascinating.
>
> Enoch: As will your grandchildren.
>
> EK: My... My grandchildren?